# How to remove the fill color of a text in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I want to add this type of text over the image. Please, help me. I just want the border of text as I have designed in the Adobe XD. Check the image for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this easily by setting the color to transparent in css

for further information check this guide: https://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/

Hope this helps

```css
.stroke-text {
  color: transparent;
  font-size: 16rem;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: black;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: white;
}

body {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class='stroke-text'>NATI</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
h1 {
  color: black;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: black;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: white;
}

body {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<h1>NATI</h1>
```

You can read more here - https://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/